# Question about frequency of visits to the US when using an ESTA

Tags: usa, esta, repeat-visits, business-class, visit

I recently travelled to the US with an ESTA, dates were 18th of August to 28th of August on a business trip.   I plan to return on the 24th of November until the 4th of December on a follow up trip - I read about 90 day limit on the ESTA - Is it acceptable to return within 90 days of a previous trip?